# Tabs that show different UIs - Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin

It sounds pretty easy, but I am stuck right now. I created a tab bar with a few tabs. Now i want to assign a certain UI to each tab, so that only the UI of the selected tab is visible. What do i have to do?

Comment: Maybe this answer will be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674116/how-to-set-different-content-for-tabs-in-vaadin14/57675685#57675685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs and presentation is separate in Vaadin 14. Add a layout below the Tabs and use `addSelectedTabListener` to react on when the user changes a tab. Then you replace the content of the layout to the appropriate content in the listener.